# How can I open the default system browser from a java fx application?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to open a web url in the default system browser from javafx. I didn't find any official documentation regard this. Any clue?

EDIT:
I've found [a tutorial](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/02/09/open-default-browser-in-javafx/) but it doesn't work.
I'm using MacOsX and I tried launching

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
```

but I get an `HeadlessExcelption`

Answer (score 46):

Use [hostServices.showDocument(location)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String)).

Try placing the following code in your application's start method:

```
getHostServices().showDocument("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Comment: What about calling this method from another classes?I have buttons in different `fxml controllers classes ` which need to open the default browser in some websites , what can i do for it :) ?

Comment: For most cases you can add a static accessor to your [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) subclass which calls `getHostServices()`.  If you want do not wish to use a static method and you want your FXML controllers to be used in multiple applications (e.g. they are library controls independent of any application), then you will need to pass the [application instance into the FXML controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

Comment: I get a `java.lang.Exception: No web browser found` :/

Answer (score 17):

Complementing jewelsea's answer, if you don't know how to call getHostServices() then try this at your main class:

```
HostServicesDelegate hostServices = HostServicesFactory.getInstance(this);
hostServices.showDocument(WEBSITE);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String)

Comment: Note that classes such as HostServicesDelegate are not part of the publicly documented JavaFX API and may not be available in later Java versions (such as Java 9).

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use `ProcessBuilder`:

```
public static void openWebpage(String url) {
    try {
        new ProcessBuilder("x-www-browser", url).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can use this option if `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri)` for some reason hangs without any error.

Answer (score 11):

Try This:

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("https://google.com").toURI());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Worked for me too.  I put it inside this   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { .... } If the system has no desktop it won't try... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#isDesktopSupported()

Comment: Hangs in Ubuntu

Comment: Working for me too.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done, seems, because this feature is not implemented : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-210

The matter is that you will not be able to launch anything, what requires awt-stack and jfx in the same VM. The decision - is to use a separate JVM. Just launch a separate VM, and accept commands on browsing by socket.

That is one way, another way - is to find any other way of browser call from java - this is a task not specific to javafx-2, but to java at all.

But developer has added a comment :

Anthony Petrov added a comment - May, 17 2013 05:09 PM
Note that FX8 allows headful AWT to run in the same VM with FX. So the AWT API should work.

Comment: this is terrible :| Thanks. I'll have to load content into the application or let the user copy paste the URL? This is an UX monster

Comment: There is webView in JavaFX =) you can load sites directly in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that works inside the scene controller, when a button is activated:

```
package sample;


import com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.HostServicesFactory;
import com.sun.javafx.application.HostServicesDelegate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller extends Application {

    public void openBrowser(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {

        HostServicesDelegate hostServices = HostServicesFactory.getInstance(this);
        getHostServices().showDocument("http://www.yahoo.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```