# how open image with url in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have banner an I wont to put it in my javaFX application. 
And when user click on the image open default browser.

```
try {
            String path = "http://developer.am/webservice/banner728x90.gif";
            URL url = new URL(path);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

also I am trying to convert above code from awt in JavaFX

Answer (score 14):

Lets see. First the ingredients:

1. [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html)
2. [Button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html)
3. [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html)
4. [Open Link in System Browser with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604341/how-can-i-open-the-default-system-browser-from-a-java-fx-application)

Putting this together:

```
String path = "http://...";
String pathToOpen = "http://...";

Image image = new Image(path);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

Button button = new Button("clickMe!", imageView);
button.setOnAction(ev -> getHostServices().showDocument(pathToOpen));
```

Comment: No problem. And if this answers your question, please mark this answer accordingly ;-)