# Opening a PDF in a javafx aplication

Tags: java, javafx

I'm developing a javafx application that opens a PDF when I pres a button. I'm using the xdg-open command in linux like this:

```
String[] command = {"xdg-open",path}
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

but when i pres the button nothing happens.
I tested it in a different project and it opened the PDF without problem.
Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: do you want to open the pdf inside the app ? or external with the system defualft program to open pdf ??

Comment: external with the system defualft program

Comment: Non FXML answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604341/how-can-i-open-the-default-system-browser-from-a-java-fx-application). FXML answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file/50775157#50775157)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getHostServices().showDocument() in a FXML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774910/gethostservices-showdocument-in-a-fxml-file)

Comment: `getHostServices().showDocument("path\to\your\pdf\file.pdf");`

Comment: @Sedrick That is not a duplicate **question** (even if the answer may be similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the method that I use. A simple call to the `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` method will open any given `File` using the system's default application.

This will also open the file in a background `Thread` so your application doesn't hang while waiting for the file to load.

```
public static void openFile(File file) throws Exception {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I added the `Desktop.isSupported()` check because it is required for some Linux environments.

Answer (score 1):

This code show the document in the default browser :

```
File file = new File("C:/filePath/Test.pdf");
HostServices hostServices = getHostServices();
hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I hope this help!!

Comment: Should be mentioned that `getHostServices` is a instance method of `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ICEpdf's `org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Document` to render the pages of my PDF's; [as described here](https://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Converting+PDF+Page+Renderings). This gives a `ava.awt.image.BufferedImage`per page. I convert this to a JavaFX node:

`Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);`

`ImageView imageView = new ImageView(fxImage);`

From there you can write your own simple paging viewer in JavaFX. The rendering is fast and the result looks as hoped for.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. The OP explicitly asked to open "external with the system defualft program".